# Insert images into td table element using Razor syntax

Tags: c#, html-table, razorengine

Am I missing something because for some reason, no image will go into this table.

I've tried with and without the width and height and I've even tried to hard code a test image url. Images will not display

```
 <table id="mediaTable" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>                
            <th>
                @*Image*@
            </th>                
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.UploadedMediaItems)
        {
            <tr id="imageName" hidden="hidden">
                <td width="200px" height="200px">
                    <img src='@Model.UploadedMediaItems[0].url' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only passing the url there. There is no img element. Put image tag there and set its src attribute to this  @Model.UploadedMediaItems[0].url

```
 <td width="200px" height="200px">
       <img src='@Model.UploadedMediaItems[0].url' alt="Meida Items" width="200" height="200" />
 </td>
```

Also its better to set min-width and height via css styles.

Comment: I missed that off my post, but in my actual code I have the img tag, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you share your exact code and also the url after it rendered.   May be the url is wrong. Are you using a relative path or an absolute path ?

Comment: Make sure after you inspect the code if there are 404 errors in the browser console for this image. If  you see then you need to modify the url little bit

Comment: I can use <div>
    <img src="@Model.UploadedMediaItems[0].url" />
</div> elsewhere in the code and works fine, so don't think the issue is the url, but yes it is giving a 404. Doens't make sense that it works outside of a table

Comment: copy the fault url that returned to view.  Open it in another tab in the browser. Then modify it to the correct one applying appropriate change and see the whether the image loads in the browser for the modified path. If it works then you know where is the issue in the url